# JSP form handling

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, input

I am currently making a jsp project called phonebook online. Its a phonebook on a browser. I'm still a beginner .
I am having a slight difficulty adding the users input to my sql database.
when i press the button to add the users input- null -shows to my database as firstname and lastname instead of the input of the user.

This are some of the line code for the input field from my Welcomeform.jsp file.

```
<td>First Name:</td>                            
<td><input type = "text" name = "fname" id="name">
</td>
<td>Last Name:</td>             
<td><input type = "text" name ="lname"  id ="name"></td>
```

This is the entire code in my adduser.jsp file.

```
<%@page language="java"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
    String firstname = request.getParameter("fname");
    String lastname = request.getParameter("lname");
    String phoneno = request.getParameter("phonenumber");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/phonebook", "**", "**");

        Statement st = conn.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("insert into  contaclist(firstname,lastname) values('"
                + firstname + "','" + lastname + "')");
        out.println("Record is added successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("error adding");
    }
%>
```

Comment: is it printing "error adding" or it's just adding empty values for firstname and lastname?

Comment: please show you entire form, does it post correctly? any stack error traced from server?

Comment: try to print your query and print the stacktrace

Comment: In HTML avoid naming different elements with same `id`.

Comment: It was printing null in the database.
Anyway, i figured it out. I changed the button the was used to submit the data to the adduser.jsp file into a submit form.
Silly me. :D

Comment: Then if this problem was just simple typographical error feel free to delete this question since it will probably will not help anyone who will read it.

Comment: Did you checked whether the request.getParameter(..) gives the value?

Answer (score 0):

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/phonebook", "**", "**");

Please make sure
that you have right access to the database 
 you can use

```
System.out.println(conn) ;
```

to check your connection

```
ResultSet rs ;
Statement st = conn.createStatement("insert into  contaclist(firstname,lastname) values("?,?")");
st.setString(1,firstname);
st.setString(2,lastname);
int k= st.executeUpdate();
System.out.println(k);
```

If  the output is 1 then record is inserted sucessfully ..